# Can I use one-hot encoded output for segmentation in Pytorch, with focal and dice losses?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I know that for classification using a neural network and CrossEntropy Loss, we need one-hot encoded output, but in PyTorch the CrossEntropy loss does not accept one-hot encoded targets, and we should give it the labels, directly and in the normal format.

Now, I am wondering if this is the same for image segmentation tasks, where the loss function is the dice loss or focal loss, etc. i.e. Is it ok if I one-hot encode the target mask for segmentation similar to tensorflow, or I cannot do that similar to classification task in Pytorch? (Lets say I am going to use a standard CNN, such as 3DUNet)

Extra note:
I have done classification with Pytorch using neural nets, it did not make sense that the cross enropy loss could not accept a one-hot encoded input. Now, I expect that for other losses that are used for segmentation, this should be the same as cross entropy loss, yet I am not sure as it won't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For classification, it is possible for `CrossEntropyLoss()` to handle one-hot targets, as specified in the [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss)

> The target that this criterion expects should contain either: class indices in the range [0,C), where C is the number of classes; or Probabilities for each class.

Therefore, you have two options for your one-hot targets:

1. use `torch.argmax()` to convert one-hot targets to class indices.
2. use it directly as targets.

For example:

```py
cross_entropy = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
input = torch.randn(3, 5)
print(f"input: {input}")
# input: tensor([[-0.6498, -0.4508,  1.0618, -1.4337, -1.6479],
#             [-0.9778,  0.0141, -0.5646, -1.0664,  0.9022],
#             [ 0.0797,  0.7878,  0.6092, -0.2396, -0.5839]])

random_idx = torch.randint(0, 5, (3,))
print(f"random_idx: {random_idx}")
# random_idx: tensor([2, 3, 3])

target_one_hot = torch.eye(5)[random_idx]
output_one_hot = cross_entropy(input, target_one_hot)
print(f"target_one_hot: {target_one_hot}")
print(f"output_one_hot: {output_one_hot}")
# target_one_hot: tensor([[0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
#                         [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
#                         [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])
# output_one_hot: 1.7241638898849487

target = target_one_hot.argmax(dim=1)
output = cross_entropy(input, target)
print(f"target: {target}")
print(f"output: {output}")
# target: tensor([2, 3, 3])
# output: 1.7241638898849487
```

For segmentation, as I explained above, it is possible to use `CrossEntropyLoss()` to handle one-hot targets. For `Dice` loss, since there is no official implementation in PyTorch and you need to implement it by yourself, and thus you can define targets as you like (one-hot or others).

Maybe you can check this [GitHub code](https://github.com/milesial/Pytorch-UNet/blob/2f62e6b1c8e98022a6418d31a76f6abd800e5ae7/train.py#L106) which implements the classical U-Net and train the model using both `CrossEntropyLoss` and `DiceLoss`

Comment: Thank you for all the information, you answered all of my questions.